# how to solve this integral ? It seems bounded and well defined integral but I don't know how to solve this

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

how to solve the following integral ? It seems well defined  i.e. bound but I could not solve it. I tried by expanding series expansion of tanh[x] but after that I got a series as an answer, which I could not sum. Is there any other method to solve it? $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tanh[x] \; e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$

Comment: @almagest $\exp \frac{(x-a)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ is only even for $a = 0$.

Comment: @lastresort. Good point. I have deleted that. There is still the difficulty that the integral is infinite unless he dropped a minus sign in the exponential.

Comment: @almagest Your other remark in that comment holds though; it ought to be $\exp \frac{(x-a)^2}{-2\sigma^2}$, which reminds me of the normal distribution.

Comment: yes.....i did a typing mistake. There is a minus sign in exponential. Its just a gaussian with non-zero mean multiplied with a tanh[x].......sorry for typing mistake

Comment: Integrand revised to agree with version reposted by OP

Comment: This is a Gaussian integral (expand $\tanh x$ into exponentials and combine them with the one you have), and I discussed how to evaluate them in [this 19 November 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=277913). See also the last two pages of [this old test](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2048374-6998850-589649/LSMSA%20multi%20test%204b.pdf) of mine.

Comment: thanks for reply. But as I mentioned that I did it using series expansion of tanh[x] but then the answer is also in series form and I could not sum that series. I want a compact answer instead of a series